# UV export layout for baking in cycles

Tags: baking

just a quick question : is it possible to save the UV map with the UV export layout when we create a mesh,  so we can just use it for do the baking and dont be obliged to unwrap again?

I hope im clear enought with my broken english.

Thanks

Comment: UV layouts are saved withing the mesh itself, not exported. You should never have to "unwrap again" unless you change your mesh, exporting is used for editing textures in external applications like Photoshop, GIMP, or other image editing software

Comment: OK thanks so i dont need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UV layouts are saved withing the mesh itself, not exported. You should never have to "unwrap again" unless you change your mesh, exporting is used for editing textures in external applications like Photoshop, GIMP, or other image editing software – Duarte Farrajota Ramos